# Unbiased Estimation of Sum of Reciprocals over a Symmetric Distribution by Taylor Expansion

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion, approximation

- Random variable $X$ follows a symmetric and unkown distribution.
- $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ are a large (~$10^6$) sample drawn from $X$
- Expectation $a = E[X]$ is known.

Consider the taylor expansion of $f(y) = \frac{1}{y}$ around $a$:

$g(y) = a^{-1} - a^{-2}(y - a) + a^{-3}(y - a)^{2}$

I guess $\sum_{n}g(x_{n})$ is not an unbiased approximation of $\sum_{n}f(x_{n})$ because the error of the Taylor expansion is not antisymmetric around $a$ for some distribution. By around I mean ±0.5 around the expectation.

Is it possible to correct the bias?

What if I am trying to fix a multi-variable Taylor expansion?

Error of the Taylor expansion when $X$ follows a uniform distribution over interval [0.5, 1.5]:

[image: Error of the taylor expansion when X is a uniform distribution.]

Comment: I'm confused. $\sum_{n}f(x_{n})$ is a random variable. You don't make _estimators_ of random variables, only of parameters. Perhaps you are trying to estimate rather $E[f(X)]$ ? I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: How about "approximation" instead of estimator? By bias, I mean the estimation has systematic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimize:

$\int_{0.5}^{1.5} g(b, c, d, y)^{2} dy + \int_{0}^{0.5} (g(b, c, d, 1 - y) - g(a, b, c, 1 + y))^{2} dy $

where $g(b, c, d, y) = 1/y - [b + c(y - 1) + d(y - 1)^{2}] $

Result:

b, c, d = 0.99265897, -1.18379802,  1.271714

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not practical for multi-variable Taylor expansion if there are lots of variables ... I want to approximate the same function around different $a$ for many times.